# Deserialize JSON property starting with @ symbol into C# dynamic object?

Tags: c#, json.net

How to deserialize Json property to dynamic object if it starts with @ symbol.

```
{
    "@size": "13",
    "text": "some text",
    "Id": 483606
}
```

I can get id and text properties like this.

```
dynamic json = JObject.Parse(txt);
string x = json.text;
```

Comment: You should show what you've tried so far.

Comment: how would you like it mapped?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since you can't use @ in a C# token name, you would need to map the @size to something else, like "SizeString" (since it is a string in your JSON above).  I use the WCF data contract attribute, but you could use the equivalent JSON attribute

```
...
[DataMember(Name = "@size")]
public string SizeString { get; set; }
...
```

Here is an example of how to deserialize the Json string.  Maybe you can adapt to your situation, or clarify your question.

```
...
string j = @"{
            ""@size"": ""13"",
            ""text"": ""some text"",
            ""Id"": 483606
        }";
        MyClass mc = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(j);
...

[DataContract]
public class MyClass
{
    [DataMember(Name="@size")]
    public string SizeString { get; set; }
    [DataMember()]
    public string text { get; set; }
    [DataMember()]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

If you don't plan loading the Json into a predefined class, you can do the following...

```
var o = JObject.Parse(j);
var x = o["text"];
var size = o["@size"];
```

Answer (score 14):

Assuming you use Json.NET:

```
public class MyObject
{
    [JsonProperty("@size")]
    public string size { get; set; }

    public string text { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json);
```